# Start a service on HPUX at boot

Tags: services, startup, hp-ux

I'm trying to start a service on `HPUX 11.31` at boot time. I generated the appropriate symlinks, but the system is not starting it up. If I run the script once the system is up, everything works as expected (but I need the service to come up at boot time by itself).

```
 $ ls -l /sbin/init.d/weblogic
 -rwxr-xr-x   1 oracle     oracle 3066 Sep 23 13:59 /sbin/init.d/weblogic

 $ ls -l /sbin/rc?.d/*weblogic
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  sys  21 Sep 23 13:38 /sbin/rc2.d/S998weblogic -> /sbin/init.d/weblogic
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  sys  21 Sep 23 13:38 /sbin/rc3.d/S998weblogic -> /sbin/init.d/weblogic
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  sys  21 Sep 23 13:38 /sbin/rc4.d/S998weblogic -> /sbin/init.d/weblogic
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weblogic server is picky about hwo it starts.  Does the script `/sbin/init.d/weblogic` start WLS as user ID root, or does it do an "su" to some WLS-specific user ID?  It seems to me that WLS refuses to run under the root user ID.

Another thing to try, change ownership of `/sbin/init.d/weblogic` to match other scripts in `/sbin/init.d/`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The script is not the problem, it runs like a charm on Linux, and the weblogic processes are spawned by the user that is supposed to run it. After a long debugging session I found the problem is HPUX and how the environment is inherited at boot time ...

Comment: Many years later, I have a question: could this be due to a `SIGHUP` being sent to all daemons when the init system completes startup? I'm seeing a report that `nohup` allows these kinds of scripts (specifically, ones that launch a JVM -- which exits when it receives a `SIGHUP`).

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz - HP-UX is weird, but not that weird, I hope. HP-UX started out as 4.2 or 4.3BSD ages ago, and HP just mutated it to fit their tastes and hardware. I'm reasonably certain that no init system sends a SIGHUP to all daemons when the system goes into multi-user mode.

Comment: @BruceEdiger This assertion came from [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58626#c0) and a little Googling came up with some other cases where simply using `nohup` with a Java process during startup would make it work. So I'm not sure what's going on. I don't have access to HP-UX, so I can't experiment with it.